# How to modify query in EF Core 2.0, before it goes to the SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this need for Persian language, where a query should first be sanitized/normalized from the point of characters.

Persian "ی" should be used instead of Arabic "ي".

In EF 6, I had an interceptor that would implement `IDbCommandInterceptor` and would change the raw SQL query using this simple line of code:

```
        command.CommandText = command.CommandText.SafePersianEncode();
```

This was hugely beneficial, reducing cost, increasing consistency, boosting quality, and preventing data cleansing requirements.

As we're migrating to EF Core 2.0, we realized that [interceptors are not there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features), and it seems that they won't be implemented in future versions too.

Since this is a very legitimate requirement, and the capability to intercept a flow is a well-known pattern (like Angular interceptors to modify ALL HTTP requests/responses in one place), and from the point of architecture it helps managing cross-cutting concerns in a neat way, what should we do now?

Is there a global way (or anyway at all) that we can modify RAW SQL query before it goes to SQL Server in EF Core 2.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

take a look at this

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/

you can override `save changes` to detect,modify changes before saving to database

Example:

```
 public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
    {
        //modify entry.Entity here
    }

    ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    var result = base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT: Simple example to change all  modified string properties**

```
public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                     e.State == EntityState.Modified))
            {
                //modify entry.Entity here
                foreach (var prop in entry.Properties)
                {
                    if ((entry.State == EntityState.Added ||
                prop.IsModified) && prop.OriginalValue is string)
                        prop.CurrentValue = prop.CurrentValue + "edited";
                }
            }

            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            var result = base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

            return result;
        }
```

this example will change any `string` property on add or edit to `xxedited` and save to database you can easily build custom rules here based on `old value` ,`property type` or accessing the entity itself. and so on